# spawn fastcgi apps on windows?

Tags: windows, fastcgi, spawn-fcgi

I wrote a toy fastcgi app using the linux example. I'd like to run it on windows now. How do i do it? I know how to spawn the process on linux and connect to it via nginx (or lighttp). I have no idea how to spawn the process on widnows. I build the app using pthreads and the fastcgi lib. spawning is my next step. I googled with no luck. I'd like to connect via nginx on windows.

How do i spawn my fastcgi app on windows? (i'm on windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I put a ifdef WIN32 and added this line`FCGX_OpenSocket(":1234", 10);` 1234 is the port and 10 is the backlog on the listen function.

Answer (score 0):

Good example worked for me (Windows CodeBlocks GCC compiler):

```
#include <fcgiapp.h>

int main()
{
    int sockfd = FCGX_OpenSocket("/var/run/myfcgiserver.sock", 1024);
    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, sockfd, 0);

    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0)
    {
        FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
        "\r\n")
        "<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
    }
}
```

from: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,1399,1439,quote=1

Comment: +0. I don't beliew non unix socket work. This question asked for windows.